# Ошибка: "Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details."

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

Не так давно начал изучать Spring MVC. Сначала создал конфигурационные файлы ApplicationContextMVS.xml и web.xml. Всё работало(приложение просто выводило "Hello World!" по адресу localhost:8080/), стоял сервер Tomcat 9.0.82. Решил установить конфигурации через Java код и аннотации, добавил зависимость jakarta, получил ошибку "cannot access jakarta.servlet.ServletException class file for jakarta.servlet.ServletException not found". Посмотрел что пишут в сети об этой ошибки и понял, что нужно поменять сервер на Tomcat V10. Скачал новы сервер, установил конфигурацию(работаю в IntelliJIDEA ultimate). По ссылке localjost:8080 у меня вылезла ошибка "HTTP Status 404. Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists".

В итоге, я пытался бороться с этой ошибкой, меняя сервер tomcat назад на V9 и установкой зависимости Javax.servlet-api. Результатом стала ошибка при подключении сервера "Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details."

Я в полнейшем ступоре, именно поэтому прошу вас помочь, потому что совершенно не понимаю в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ru.learning.springMVC</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-app1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-mvc-app1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

    <spring.version>6.0.13</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>




  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-app1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Класс SpringConfig:

```
package ru.learning.springMVC.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.learning.springMVC")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

Класс MySpringMVCDispetcherServletInitilaizer:

```
package ru.learning.springMVC.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMVCDispetcherServletInitilaizer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

Текс ошибки:

```
C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15\bin\catalina.bat run
[2023-10-22 05:39:41,502] Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\3ee6d4c3-f8db-4047-aceb-bf8732e6ba68"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.1.15
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.608 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 11 2023 23:38:40 UTC
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.608 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.1.15.0
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.608 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ РћРЎ:             10.0
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log РђСЂС…РёС‚РµРєС‚СѓСЂР°:           amd64
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ JVM:            17.0.8+9-LTS-211
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log РџСЂРѕРёР·РІРѕРґРёС‚РµР»СЊ JVM:     Oracle Corporation
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\3ee6d4c3-f8db-4047-aceb-bf8732e6ba68
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\3ee6d4c3-f8db-4047-aceb-bf8732e6ba68\conf\logging.properties
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.620 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.620 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.620 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.621 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\3ee6d4c3-f8db-4047-aceb-bf8732e6ba68\jmxremote.password
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.622 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\3ee6d4c3-f8db-4047-aceb-bf8732e6ba68\jmxremote.access
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.622 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.623 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.623 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.623 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.624 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.624 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.624 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.625 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.625 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.2\tomcat\3ee6d4c3-f8db-4047-aceb-bf8732e6ba68
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.625 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.625 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15\temp
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.632 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.920 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Р�РЅРёС†РёР°Р»РёР·Р°С†РёСЏ ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Oct-2023 17:39:42.956 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [684] milliseconds
22-Oct-2023 17:39:43.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
22-Oct-2023 17:39:43.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
22-Oct-2023 17:39:43.058 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Oct-2023 17:39:43.130 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [174] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2023-10-22 05:39:43,253] Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
22-Oct-2023 17:39:43.909 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [manageApp]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1824)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering. Duplicate fragments found in [[file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-6.0.13.jar, file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.24.jar]].
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2175)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2131)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1299)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:991)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4766)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        ... 43 more
22-Oct-2023 17:39:43.911 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [createStandardContext]
    javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method [manageApp]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:304)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1824)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering. Duplicate fragments found in [[file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-6.0.13.jar, file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.24.jar]].
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2175)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2131)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1299)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:991)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4766)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        ... 43 more
[2023-10-22 05:39:43,939] Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
22-Oct-2023 17:39:53.083 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15\webapps\manager]
22-Oct-2023 17:39:53.662 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\worksplace\Projects\apache-tomcat-10.1.15\webapps\manager] has finished in [577] ms
```

[[image: Вот "Edit configurations"1]

Comment: `More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering. Duplicate fragments found in [[file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-6.0.13.jar, file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/worksplace/Projects/SpringMVCApp1/SpringMVCApp1/target/spring-mvc-app1/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.24.jar]`

Comment: @ArchDemon .  Sorry, it didn't help, I deleted all versions of Web MVC listed in the folder except the one I was using. Did not help :"[2023-10-22 11:19:52,857] Artifact spring-mvc-app1:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details."

Comment: Ну у вас уже другая ошибка, на деплое. Нужен новый лог, как говорится в сообщении ошибки. Или удалили неправильно и они заново подгрузились.